# TinySlider: Make prev/next buttons disappear when at first/last index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Haven't been able to find a solution but when using [Tiny Slider](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/) and using custom controls, my carousel controls appear permanently. The regular functionality just disables the button but still remains visible. I want to hide the previous button when the user is at the start of the carousel and hide the next button when at the end.

I've tried reading the disabled attribute to toggle the previous/next buttons but it doesn't work as expected.

```html
$(document).on("click",".next", function() {
  var nextCheck = $(this).attr("aria-disabled");
  if (nextCheck) { $(this).hide();} else {$(this).show();  $(".prev").show(); }
});

$(document).on("click",".prev", function() {
   var prevCheck = $(this).attr("aria-disabled");
   if (prevCheck)  { $(this).hide();} else {$(".next").show(); }
 });
```

It properly hides the "next" button when it reaches the end but it never reappears when I start to move back. The "previous" button also disappears after a click and both buttons just entirely disappear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need javascript. You can solve that problem with css only.

```css
.next[aria-disabled=true],
.prev[aria-disabled=true] {
   display: none;
}

.next[aria-disabled=false],
.prev[aria-disabled=false] {
   display: block;
}
```